# What are some good, reasonably-priced SQL Server client tools offering Intellisense for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, intellisense

SSMS 2008 doesn't have SQL Intellisense when connected to SQL Server 2005! I know of 3 products which enable writing SQL with Intellisense. ApexSQL Edit, Red Gate's SQL Prompt Pro & [SQL Assistant](http://www.softtreetech.com/isql.htm). However I am looking for a less expensive solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cheaper? What about your SQL Server license cost in comparison...?

Comment: Developer edition is free. Plus the company pays for the server but doesn't want to pay $$ just to get Intellisense. It's a nice to have feature, not detriment to do any kind work.

Comment: @John Sansom: 'Less expensive' to 'cheaper'? This type of editing on SO is getting just too anal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embrace Linq and use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/).

Full intellisense using linq on sql servers, fully integrated with c# statements or expressions, for [$27](http://www.linqpad.net/Purchase.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Those are pretty much the three choices.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pay for an add-in, you could always roll your own (although in the long run it may be cheaper to just pay for an existing solution).  Jon Sayce has a good blog post on [Building a SSMS Add-In](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/jonsayce/archive/2008/01/15/building-a-sql-server-management-studio-addin.aspx) if you want to give it a shot.

Comment: it will take me weeks or months to roll my own. Of course it's a ton cheaper to buy a commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

My Recommendation: [Atlantis SQL Enywhere](http://www.atlantis-interactive.co.uk/products/default.aspx) which is completely free. It works with SQL Server 2005 and 2008. I have been using it for a month now and I am really impressed with its features. Keyboard shortcuts are similar to VS, so makes the transition is really smooth to a new editor.

Some of the features that are worth mentioning.

1. Intellisense that actually works when using multiple tables and joins with aliases
2. Suggestion of joins when using multiple tables (reduces time on typing, really neat)
3. Rich formatting of sql code.
4. Better representation of SQL plans
5. Highlights variables declarations while they are used.
6. Table definition on mouse hover.

Productivity++.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a freeware tool that works with SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008. Recently we have released [dbForge SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/), a free SQL autocomplete add-in for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

[image: dbForge SQL Complete running in SSMS]

Answer (score 0):

By the way, on Friday (21 January 2011), we have released a new version of [SQL Complete](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/) that offers a [bunch of new features](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/features.html). All new features are available in shareware Standard Edition (30-days free trial, $49.95).

You also can get all basic functionality, similar to v. 1.0, with Express Edition.